# How to cleanly disconnect JFrog X-ray from Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-xray

I was looking at a trial of jFrog X-ray.
Setup was pretty easy. During install I had to provide the Artifactory URL and a Join key.
All was fine. Now I would like to disconnect X-ray from Artifactory.
What is the right way of doing this without having any impact on my Artifactory Repos?

Thanks
Kristian

Answer (score 2):

JFrog Xray can be disabled or disconnected from Artifactory by just unchecking the Xray Enabled option by going to the Administration module, then to Xray Security and Compliance | Advanced, and clicking Settings.
[Xray](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Configuring+Xray#ConfiguringXray-AdvancedSettings)